# Minimizing SSE using Scipy.optimize minimize

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to optimize SSE (sum of squared error) of a function using `scipy.optimize`. To test with, I created a simple problem as below code.
But the optimized parameters output by scipy never makes SSE=0. Can someone help me to understand, where am I going wrong.

I tried to cross check with the SSE calculated by my code with the one computed in excel. It matched. Then I used minimize function to minimize that SSE function, the ones computed by Scipy is not matching with the hand calculated ones. The function I used to is of form (y=ax+b). Below is the code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


e=np.array([0,2])
sig1=np.array([0,200])
k = [10,10]
#n = 0.2
coe=np.array([k[0],k[1]])

def sig2(e):
    v=(k[0]*e)+ k[1]
    SEzip = zip(sig1, v)
    sse = 0
    for y in SEzip:
        sse += np.power((y[0] - y[1]),2)
    return sse

print (sig2(e))
def f(coe):
   print(coe)
   return f
result = minimize(sig2,coe,method='Nelder-Mead',callback=(f),options={'xtol': 1e-6,'ftol':1e-06,'maxiter':50000,'disp': True,'adaptive' : True})

print(result)
```

Comment: It will be of great help if someone can help me out to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were printing your `x0` aka `coe` in here, I edited your code and shortened your objective function `sig2()` into one line then edited your callback to display the variable tested and its equivalent objective function value. Now you can clearly see that `sse=0` is reached.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# for prettier numpy prints
np.set_printoptions(precision = 6)

# init 
e    = np.array([0,2])
sig1 = np.array([0,200])
k    = [10, 10]
coe  = np.array([k[0], k[1]])

# define objective function
def sig2(e):
    return sum([np.power((y[0] - y[1]), 2) for y in zip(sig1, (k[0]*e)+ k[1])])

# define callback
def f(e):
   print("e: %25s | sig2(e): %5s" % (e,round(sig2(e), 6)))

# optimize
result = minimize(sig2,
                  coe,
                  method   = 'Nelder-Mead',
                  callback = f,
                  options  = {'xtol': 1e-6,'ftol':1e-06,
                              'maxiter':50000,'disp': True,'adaptive' : True})

print(result)
```

Output:

```
...
e:     [-1.000053 18.999751] | sig2(e): 6e-06
e:     [-1.000062 19.000109] | sig2(e): 2e-06
e:     [-1.000062 19.000109] | sig2(e): 2e-06
e:     [-1.000062 19.000109] | sig2(e): 2e-06
e:     [-0.999934 18.999981] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.000049 18.999979] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.000027 19.000044] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999986 18.999996] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999986 18.999996] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999986 18.999996] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.000009 18.999993] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.000009 18.999993] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999995 19.      ] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999995 19.      ] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.000003 18.999998] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.       19.000002] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999998 19.      ] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.000001 18.999999] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-1.       19.000001] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:     [-0.999999 19.      ] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:                 [-1. 19.] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:                 [-1. 19.] | sig2(e):   0.0
e:                 [-1. 19.] | sig2(e):   0.0
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 56
         Function evaluations: 110
 final_simplex: (array([[-1., 19.],
       [-1., 19.],
       [-1., 19.]]), array([6.221143e-12, 1.914559e-11, 1.946860e-11]))
           fun: 6.2211434216849394e-12
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 110
           nit: 56
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([-1., 19.])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I see the predicted optimum is not correct. Though Scipy output shows sse=0,  if I substitute the predicted values, sse=33850.. The optimal value should be (100,0).

Comment: Where are you substituting the values? `sig2(np.array([-1, 19])) =  0` and `sig2(np.array([100, 0])) =  1056200 `?

Comment: Yes, I am manually substituting on the same equation to cross check the results. I checked in excel sheet as well

Comment: In that case your implementation of `sig2()` does not match your function that you are substituting into. Good luck.

Comment: when i print `sig2()` the first value is perfectly matching with the hand calculation. This means that the function is correct.

Comment: Just because one value somehow matches, it does not mean it is correct. You should check at least for 3 random values.

Comment: I tried with many random pairs for `k[0]` & `k[1]` and `print(sig2(e)`. all the values are computed correctly.  Is there something missing on `scipy.optimize.minimze` function?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I was passing wrong variable into the function.. sig2(e) should be sig2(k). Now it is working perfect!!!